# How to get new version warning in Build.gradle with pre-defined dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

When you reference a dependency directly in gradle, IntelliJ gives a lint warning if there is a newer version. i.e. `implementation 'com.library:name:1.0.0'` gives a warning that version 1.0.1 is available.

If, however, you reference the library via a gradle ext. property, it does not give that warning. i.e. `implementation deps.library.name` does not give a warning. Is there any way I can still get that warning while referencing previously defined libraries?

In my case I have several modules that re-use a lot of the same libraries, so it's important to be able to define all the libraries and their versions in one place and then just refer to them from each module that needs them. But this causes me to no longer be told by the IDE when there are new version. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a feature of Android Studio and indeed it does not support all the ways a dependency can be defined in Gradle.

An equivalent can be achieved with the [plugin `gradle-versions-plugin`](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) through its `dependencyUpdates` task.